# POM Error when importing OSM source code as a Module in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, osmdroid

I can't import the source code to my project, getting the following error when gradle runs:
'Error:Cannot get property 'pom' on extra properties extension as it does not exist'

I'm using Android Studio and already run the gradle clean build command before import it. As a Project, the gradle compile OSM and runs just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This problem was fixed using this solution: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/372#issuecomment-240398087